# Equal holomorphic injective functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have this problem:

> Given a disc $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ with center $z_0$, let $f_1,f_2$ injective holomorphic functions in $D$ such that
>
> - $f_1(D)=f_2(D)$
> - $f_1(z_0)=f_2(z_0)$
> - $f´_1(z_0)=f´_2(z_0)$
>
> Prove that $f_1=f_2$.

What I know is that if I define the function $g(z)=f_1(z)-f_2(z)$, then I can see that $g(z_0)=g´(z_0)=0$, but I can-t see more than this. Could anyone tell me a way to attack the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f_2$ is injective and $f_1(D) = f_2(D)$, $G = f_2^{-1} \circ f_1$ is well-defined and analytic, mapping $D$ into itself.  Note that $G(z_0) = z_0$ and $G'(z_0) = 1$, and apply Schwarz's lemma.